# SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported (SWEET32) - Nessus Plugin ID 42873

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I received the following error when I scan ubuntu 16.4 . on port 10250.

```
# netstat -nltp | grep 10250
```

tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      849/kubelet

Anyidea how to fix this issue?

Description

The remote host supports the use of SSL ciphers that offer medium strength encryption. Nessus regards medium strength as any encryption that uses key lengths at least 64 bits and less than 112 bits, or else that uses the 3DES encryption suite.

Note that it is considerably easier to circumvent medium strength encryption if the attacker is on the same physical network.

Output from most recent scan

Medium Strength Ciphers (> 64-bit and < 112-bit key, or 3DES)

```
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA       Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
DES-CBC3-SHA                 Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1
```

The fields above are :

```
{OpenSSL ciphername}
Kx={key exchange}
Au={authentication}
Enc={symmetric encryption method}
Mac={message authentication code}
{export flag}
```

Solution
Reconfigure the affected application if possible to avoid use of medium strength ciphers.

Answer (score 0):

Kubelet is a [Kubernetes cluster node component](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#node-components). It uses TLS to communicate with kube-apiserver container on a Kubernetes cluster master node.

According to Kubelet [reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/):

> **--tls-cipher-suites** stringSlice
>   Comma-separated list of cipher suites for the server. **If omitted, the [default Go cipher suites](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/cipher_suites.go) will be used.**

```
Possible values: 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
```

In the cluster created using [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) tool this options is not configured by default.

On Ubuntu it is convenient to specify `kubelet` options in the `/etc/default/kubelet` file:
*(This is just an example of argument usage. Choose kubelet options based on your knowledge and requirements.)*

```
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--tls-cipher-suites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

You have to set this option the same for all nodes in the cluster.

Restart kubelet service to apply extra arguments.

Comment: Hello @user202304. Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ?